# Simplifying function $f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x+3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you simplify this function to

$$ f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x+3}= 2-\frac{5}{x+3} $$

I've tried few different things but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe,

$$f(x)=\frac{2x+1}{x+3}=\frac{2(x+3)-5}{x+3}=\frac{2(x+3)}{x+3}-\frac{5}{x+3}={2}-\frac{5}{x+3}$$

Answer (score 0):

In this type of question you should work through reverse calculation.
Like, What we have to make,
$$2-\dfrac{5}{x+3}$$
$$=\dfrac{2(x+3)-5}{x+3}$$
$$=\dfrac{2x+6-5}{x+3}$$
$$=\dfrac{2x+1}{x+3}$$
Hope,it will make sense to you.